# Can you build Sharepoint 2010 webparts with VS 2010 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Can you?  I'm looking to build the Sharepoint Visual Web Parts.

I downloaded C# express and Web Developer Express but neither have the templates that all of the walkthroughs start from.

Is there any way I can get the template or do I HAVE to get the professional version.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Web parts or Visual Web Parts? You can build Web Parts, which are really hosted in the ASP.NET namespace and not SharePoint with express. The downside is you need to build your control tree via code. It's not as easy as the Visual Web Part that is part of VS 2010.

Try this link to see if it helps

http://asp.dotnetheaven.com/aspnet/doc/webparts/custom.aspx

Not sure if the WSP Builder templates are part of VS express, but that would make creating the deployment package easier.

Comment: I was looking to build a visual web part.  I figure I can get them to get me an actual copy of VS2010 if I can prove that this IS simple.

Comment: MS Visual Web part is essentially a take off of Son of Smart part. It essentially is a web part that hosts a user control (ascx) file. You may want to look into that as an option if you can't get a copy of VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting tool for your questions

[SharePoint 2010 Dev tools](http://sharepointdevtools.codeplex.com/)

I have no tried VS 2010 Express, but it seems you will need SP2010 for development on VS 2010.

So, you need to figure out to install [WSPBuilder on VS 2010 Express](http://keutmann.blogspot.com/2009/12/wspbuilder-2010-beta.html)